# Principal Component Analysis C++ OpenCV

Tags: c++, image, opencv, pca

I am new to OpenCV and I am trying to implement Principal Component Analysis (Eigenspace) on  [AT&T database](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/research/dtg/attarchive/facedatabase.html). The eigenvalues come in order of 10^6. The outcome is disappointing since images seem to be projected randomly on space of eigenvectors. Distance^2 between similar as well as dissimilar images in the order of 10^8. Following is my code:

Some constants :

```
const int ROWSIZE = 112; //number of rows per image
const int COLSIZE = 92; //number of columns per image
int ROW = 92*112; //each image is represented as a column of size ROW*1
int PEOPLE = 3; // number of people in training set
int FACES = 3; // number of faces used per person
int COL = PEOPLE*FACES; //total number of training faces
static const double THRESHOLD = 0.9; //fraction of energy of eigenvalue to be chosen
```

Following are the steps:
Load image to image matrix, convert to CV_64F format and convert image in the training set to a column.

```
img.convertTo(img1, CV_64F);
for (int i = 1; i <= PEOPLE; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= FACES; j++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < ROWSIZE; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < COLSIZE; y++) {
                images.at<double>(x*COLSIZE+y, (i-1)*FACES+j-1) = 
                img1.at<double>(x, y);
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Convert testImage to single column.

Compute the average of all columns and subtract mean using

```
    Mat avg(ROW, 1, CV_64F, double(0));
    for (int j = 0; j < COL; j++) {
        avg += images.col(j);
    }
    avg = avg / COL;
    for (int j = 0; j < COL; j++) {
        images.col(j) = images.col(j) - avg;
    }
```

Compute eigenvalues and eigenvectors for images.t()*images() since it has low dimensionality

```
    Mat eig_val(COL, 1, CV_64F, double(0));
    Mat eig_vec(COL, COL, CV_64F, double(0));   
    eigen((images.t()*images), eig_val, eig_vec);
```

Compute significant eigenvalues using

```
    double totalSum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < COL; i++) {
        totalSum += sqrt(eig_val.at<double>(i, 0));
    }
    double sum = 0; int k = 0;
    for (k = 0; k < COL; k++) {
        sum += sqrt(eig_val.at<double>(k, 0));
        if (sum > THRESHOLD*totalSum)break;
    }
    int sigValue = k + 1;
```

Compute normalized eigenvectors of initial images matrix. Please note that eigenvectors are the rows of eig_vec matrix

```
    Mat featureVec(sigValue, ROW, CV_64F, double(0));
    for (int i = 0; i < sigValue; i++) {
            featureVec.row(i) = eig_vec.row(i)*images.t();
            Mat d = featureVec.row(i)*featureVec.row(i).t();
            featureVec.row(i) = featureVec.row(i) / sqrt(d.at<double>(0,0));
    }
```

Compute transformed training vectors and test vectors

```
    Mat transformedData = featureVec*images;
    Mat transformedTestImage = featureVec*testImage;
```

Obtain index of training image with least distance from test image

```
    int imageIndex = -1; double currMin = 1000000000.0;
    for (int j = 0; j < COL; j++) {
        Mat mat = (transformedData.col(j).t() - transformedTestImage.col(0).t())*(transformedData.col(j) - transformedTestImage.col(0));
        if (currMin > mat.at<double>(0,0)){
            imageIndex = j;
            currMin = mat.at<double>(0, 0);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're considering the pixel representation of an image? And wondering why similar images don't have similar eigenvectors? It helps to understand the basics of images and matrixes. While both are rectangular and contain numbers, they're far from the same. For instance, a one pixel shift is a meaningful but trivial operation. The equivalent operation on a matrix might not even make sense and is anything but trivial.

Comment: Yes, I am considering pixel representation of an image. After obtaining eigenvectors from training set, similar images should have close projection on the space of eigenvectors, i.e, some kind of clustering should form for similar images. But, it is not happening!! And I am unable to understand why is this the case?

Comment: @MSalters If you are asking not to work with matrices, what am i supposed to use? All the tutorials use matrix only. We can interpret change in an entry as a pixel shift in a matrix also. Why is this an issue?

Comment: Well, the typical step would be feature extraction, such that similar images have similar features. PCA can then reduce the effective number of features.